# Is it possible to print out the shell expansion?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, expansion

I know there is a specific set of rules that shell expand the commands user typed. (let's talk about bash shell.)

Is it possible to print out a command in the form after shell expansion? It seems to be a good utility to learn and make sure how shell expands special characters.

e.g.

```
$ echo *

{all the filenames in current dir}
```

I want to print out the expanded command, which is the following line:

```
echo {all the filenames in .}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `echo`...put it in front of the command you want to expand. I use this quite frequently.

```
$ ls
one.txt
two.txt
three.dat
$ echo rm *.txt
rm one.txt two.txt
$ rm *.txt
```

You can use <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd> to quickly add/remove the preceding `echo`.

**EDIT**
As [pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/861077/is-it-possible-to-print-out-the-shell-expansion/861089?noredirect=1#comment1141926_861089) in the comments, this will not work if the command is not just a simple command (like if it is a `for` loop, uses the pipe `|`, or `&&` or anything else like that).

Comment: This is what I do when testing a script

Comment: This is still affected by other shell tokens `echo cat * | someprogram` doesn't do what you might think from this answer.

Comment: To delete the preceding `echo` word just use Alt+D instead of pressing Del many times

Answer (score 18):

You can use `set -x`.

For example, consider the script:

```
$ cat script.sh
set -x
echo *
```

When run, it shows the expanded `echo` statement before actually executing it:

```
$ bash script.sh
+ echo file1 file2 file3 script.sh
file1 file2 file3 script.sh
```

And, as Kundor points out, this also works *interactively* on the command line:

```
$ set -x
+ set -x
$ echo *
+ echo file1 file2 file3 script.sh
file1 file2 file3 script.sh
```

#### Documentation

`man bash` explains what `set -x` does as follows:

> After  expanding  each  simple command, for command, case command,
>   select command, or
>                         arithmetic for command, display the expanded value of PS4, followed  by  the  command
>                         and its expanded arguments or associated word list.

The default value for `PS4` is, as shown above, a plus sign followed by a space.

Comment: And it works fine in an interactive shell, too (which I think the OP is looking for.)

Answer (score 9):

For an interactive shell, pressing `Ctrl+x` followed by `*` after typing the glob pattern will edit your command line with that glob pattern expanded.  From the bash man page:

> glob-expand-word (`C-x *`)
>
> The  word  before  point  is  treated  as a pattern for pathname
>   expansion, and the list of  matching  file  names  is  inserted,
>   replacing  the  word.   If  a  numeric  argument is supplied, an
>   asterisk is appended before pathname expansion.

You might also be interested in glob-list-expansions (`Ctrl+x`, `g`).

Comment: I am using bash from Mac OS. I tried ctrl+x, command+x. I am not sure if it does any command line editing. could you elaborate more?

Comment: @WeishiZeng I don't know why it's not working for you.  Did you press `Ctrl+x, *` immediately after typing `echo *` and before pressing the enter key?  If it still doesn't work, you could modify `~/.inputrc` and bind glob-expand-word to something else.

Comment: contrl+x moves cursor to the word echo, but doesn't edit anything. "Ctrl+x, *" what does it mean?? (is it ctrl+x OR ctrl+*??) * is on Shift, so I need to press Shift as well to get a *, right?

Comment: Right, press `Ctrl+x` followed by `Shift+8`.  You could try seing if `Ctrl+x, g` works, or, as I said earlier, assign your own key in the `.inputrc` file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see how arguments are expanded or tokenized, you can use a program or script that prints out its arguments. Here's one implementation in `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i = 0; i <= $#; ++i )); do
    printf 'argv[%d] = %s\n' $i "${!i}"
done
```

Assuming you put that in a file called `printargs.sh` (and made it executable), then you would get output like this

```
$ ./printargs.sh a{1..3}b
argv[0] = ./printargs.sh
argv[1] = a1b
argv[2] = a2b
argv[3] = a3b
```